# Merge 2 Hash and create third new Hash in Ruby 2.6.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge

I wish create a new hash from the following two hashes.

```
invoiced_data =
  {"Jan 2020"=>0, "Feb 2020"=>0, "Mar 2020"=>0, "Apr 2020"=>0,
   "May 2020"=>0, "Jun 2020"=>0, "Jul 2020"=>0.331027548e7,
   "Aug 2020"=>0.31668664e6, "Sep 2020"=>0, "Oct 2020"=>0,
   "Nov 2020"=>0, "Dec 2020"=>0}

payment_transaction_data =
  {"Jul 2020"=>400.0, "Aug 2020"=>26924.0}
```

All keys of the latter hash are keys of the former hash. The latter hash could be empty.

The hash I wish to construct has the same keys as `invoiced_data`. The values of those keys are hashes with keys `:Invoiced_data` and `:payment_transaction_type`. The values of `:Invoiced_data` are to to be the value of `invoiced_data` for the given key and the values of `:payment_transaction_type` are to be the value of `payment_transaction_data` for the given key, if the key is present, else zero. The result I need is as follows.

```
{"Jan 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},        
 "Feb 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},         
 "Mar 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},             
 "Apr 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},        
 "May 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},         
 "Jun 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},        
 "Jul 2020": {Invoiced_data: 3310275.48, payment_transaction_data: 400.0},
 "Aug 2020": {Invoiced_data: 316686.64, payment_transaction_data: 26924.0},
 "Sep 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},        
 "Oct 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},        
 "Nov 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0},        
 "Dec 2020": {Invoiced_data: 0, payment_transaction_data: 0}}
```

Comment: I trust you approve of my edit, but don't hesitate to to rollback or re-edit. You stated (sic), "I want to create new hash with the all the keys of `Invoiced_data`, as `payment_transaction_data` might not have all the keys [of `Invoiced_data`]". By that I assumed you meant `payment_transaction_data` has no keys that are not keys of `Invoiced_data`, but I may be wrong as some answers evidently interpreted that as meaning `payment_transaction_data` could have keys that are not keys of `Invoiced_data` in which case the hash returned should include those keys. Please edit if I had misundersood.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that it might be more optimized, but fast solution:

```rb
a
=> {"Jan 2020"=>0, "Feb 2020"=>0, "Mar 2020"=>0, "Apr 2020"=>0, "May 2020"=>0, "Jun 2020"=>0, "Jul 2020"=>3310275.48, "Aug 2020"=>316686.64, "Sep 2020"=>0, "Oct 2020"=>0, "Nov 2020"=>0, "Dec 2020"=>0}

b
=> {"Jul 2020"=>400.0, "Aug 2020"=>26924.0}

a.map do |k, v|
  [k, { Invoiced_data: v || 0, payment_transaction_data: b[k] || 0 }]
end.to_h
=> {"Jan 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Feb 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Mar 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Apr 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "May 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Jun 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Jul 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>3310275.48, :payment_transaction_data=>400.0}, "Aug 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>316686.64, :payment_transaction_data=>26924.0}, "Sep 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Oct 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Nov 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}, "Dec 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
invoiced_data = {'Jun 2020' => 0.3310273458e7, 'Jul 2020' => 0.331027548e7, 'Aug 2020' => 0.31668664e6}
payment_transaction_data = {'Jul 2020' => 400, 'Aug 2020' => 26924.0, 'Sep 2020' => 25834.0}

hash = {}
(invoiced_data.keys | payment_transaction_data.keys).each do |key|
  hash[key] = {}
  hash[key][:invoiced_data] = invoiced_data[key] || 0.0
  hash[key][:payment_transaction_data] = payment_transaction_data[key] || 0
end
```

then

```
puts hash # {"Jun 2020"=>{:invoiced_data=>3310273.458, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
 "Jul 2020"=>{:invoiced_data=>3310275.48, :payment_transaction_data=>400}, 
 "Aug 2020"=>{:invoiced_data=>316686.64, :payment_transaction_data=>26924.0}, 
 "Sep 2020"=>{:invoiced_data=>0.0, :payment_transaction_data=>25834.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
invoice_data = {"Jan 2020"=>0, "Feb 2020"=>0, "Mar 2020"=>0, "Apr 2020"=>0, "May 2020"=>0, "Jun 2020"=>0, "Jul 2020"=>0.331027548e7, "Aug 2020"=>0.31668664e6, "Sep 2020"=>0, "Oct 2020"=>0, "Nov 2020"=>0, "Dec 2020"=>0}
transaction_data = {"Jul 2020"=>400.0, "Aug 2020"=>26924.0}


{}.tap do |result|
  keys = invoice_data.keys + transaction_data.keys
  keys.uniq.each do |key|
    result[key] ||= {}
    result[key][:invoice_data] = invoice_data[key] || 0
    result[key][:transaction_data] = transaction_data[key] || 0
  end
end
```

Result:

```
 => {"Jan 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Feb 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Mar 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Apr 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "May 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Jun 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Jul 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>3310275.48, :transaction_data=>400.0}, "Aug 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>316686.64, :transaction_data=>26924.0}, "Sep 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Oct 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Nov 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}, "Dec 2020"=>{:invoice_data=>0, :transaction_data=>0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows.

```
invoiced_data.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = { Invoiced_data: v,
  payment_transaction_data: payment_transaction_data.fetch(k,0) } }
  #=> {"Jan 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Feb 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Mar 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Apr 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "May 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Jun 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Jul 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>3310275.48,
  #                 :payment_transaction_data=>400.0},
  #    "Aug 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>316686.64,
  #                 :payment_transaction_data=>26924.0},
  #    "Sep 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Oct 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Nov 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0},
  #    "Dec 2020"=>{:Invoiced_data=>0, :payment_transaction_data=>0}}
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).